# Como obter o dia com duas casas em JS

Tags: javascript

Tenho um form do tipo date, e preciso gerar o 'min' e 'max' dele de acordo com a data atual. Fiz uma função que calcula essa data e seta isso no form. O problema é que o valor do dia está vindo com 1 casa e no html eu preciso de duas casas. Segue a função:

```
function getDataMinima(){
        var dataMinima = new Date();
        dataMinima.setFullYear(dataMinima.getFullYear()-130);
        var dataForm = dataMinima.getFullYear() + '-' + dataMinima.getMonth() + '-' + dataMinima.getDate();
        console.log("entrou na função minima, data calculada:"+dataForm);

        var dataMaxima = new Date();
        dataMaxima.setFullYear(dataMaxima.getFullYear()-5);
        var dataMaximaForm = dataMaxima.getFullYear() + '-' + dataMaxima.getMonth() + '-' +dataMaxima.getDate();
        console.log("Entrou na funcao maxima, data calculada:"+dataMaximaForm);

        $("#campodata").attr({
             "min" : dataForm
        });
    }
```

Meu problema é que quando esse valor é passado para o html, eu obtenho: '1888-11-3', e o '3' ao invés de '03' faz com que a regra seja ignorada, existe alguma forma de formatar isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem formas melhores de se fazer isso. Segue uma delas:

```js
function getDataMinima(){
    var dataMinima = new Date();
    dataMinima.setFullYear(dataMinima.getFullYear()-130);
    console.log("entrou na função minima, data calculada:"+dataMinima.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
    
    var dataMaxima = new Date();
    dataMaxima.setFullYear(dataMaxima.getFullYear()-5);
    console.log("Entrou na funcao maxima, data calculada:"+dataMaxima.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
    
    $("#campodata").attr({
         "min" : dataMinima.toISOString().split('T')[0]
    });
}
```

Explicação:

O método `toISOString()` irá formatar um objeto de data numa data estilo `YYYY-MM-DDTHH-mm-sssZ`. Como você quer só a data, o `split('T')` irá quebrar a string no T, e o `[0]` irá pegar só a string de data (`[1]` vai ter a string de hora, caso precise para algo).

Para mais informações:

[Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode usar o método [`String.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) para preencher o número com zeros a esquerda.

Sua sintaxe é:

```
minha_string.padStart(tamanho)
// ou
minha_string.padStart(tamanho, string_de_preenchimento)
```

Onde `string_de_preenchimento` é, por padrão, espaço ().

Exemplo:

```js
let numero = "3";

console.log(numero.padStart(2));      // ' 3'
console.log(numero.padStart(2, '0')); // '03'
console.log(numero.padStart(4, '0')); // '0003'
console.log(numero.padStart(4, 'X')); // 'XXX3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão é criar uma função auxiliar para retornar a data no formato que você deseja.

```
function getDataFormatada(data) {
    return data.getFullYear() + '-'
        + ('0' + (data.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-'
        + ('0' + data.getDate()).slice(-2);
}

function getDataMinima(){
    var dataMinima = new Date();
    dataMinima.setFullYear(dataMinima.getFullYear()-130);
    var dataFormatada = getDataFormatada(dataMinima);
    console.log("entrou na função minima, data calculada:"+ dataFormatada);

    var dataMaxima = new Date();
    dataMaxima.setFullYear(dataMaxima.getFullYear()-5);
    console.log("Entrou na funcao maxima, data calculada:"+ getDataFormatada(dataMaxima));

    $("#campodata").attr({
         "min" : dataFormatada
    });
}
```